# Faster way to get table columns than info schema?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following to get the column names from a table:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = mytable
```

But it takes a very long time to respond.  Is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the schema and only select the columns you require:

```
  SELECT table_schema, 
         table_name, 
         column_name, 
         data_type, 
         character_maximum_length,
         is_nullable, 
         column_default, 
         numeric_precision, 
         numeric_scale
    FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE table_name = 'yourtable' 
     AND table_schema = 'yourschema'
ORDER BY table_schema, 
         table_name, 
         ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a mysql + php solution

```
$query =    'EXPLAIN ' . $this->tableName;
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();

        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
            $this->dbColumns[] = $row['Field'];
        }
```

Seems pretty fast